# How Upload file from EFS (WinSCP) to WebHDFS (Hue/Cloudera) in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cloudera, winscp, powershell-ise, webhdfs

I've been trying to break down that problem in two parts in order to automate that:

1. PowerShell: Transfer file from local Desktop to EFS (via WinSCP) - OK
2. PowerShell: Get that same file on EFS (via WinSCP) and Put it into Cloudera WebHDFS (we use the Hue interface) - NOK

In the part (**1**), I created the following code:

```sh
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"

# Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "peanut-edgenode1.dundlermufflin.com"
    UserName = "JoeStreet"
    Password = "dundlermufflin123"
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-ed28549 255 HJGF564hjfq8if1Y8KYALtf6zEv+z3o="
}

$sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("Cipher", "aes,chacha20,3des,WARN,des,blowfish,arcfour")
$sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyHost", "web.isa.la.proxy.dundlermufflin.com")
$sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyPort", "4200")
$sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyUsername", "na%5CJoeStreet")
$sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyPassword", "dundlermufflin123")

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Your code
    $session.PutFiles("C:\Users\JoeStreet\Documents\report-2021-02-02_no_locations.xlsx", "/efs/home/JoeStreet/report-2021-02-02_no_locations.xlsx").Check()
}
finally
{
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

But...if I want to transfer from EFS (WinSCP) to Cloudera WebHDFS, via PuTTY we login to `peanut-edgenode1.dundlermufflin.com` and execute the following: [the part (**2**) above]

```sh
hdfs dfs -put -f /efs/home/JoeStreet/report-2021-02-02_no_locations.xlsx /prd/product/ssa_stg/JoeStreet/
```

which goes fine.

But how could I insert that command in PowerShell?

I tried to put in different ways in `$session.PutFiles(origin, destiny).Check()` but got no success...

Answer (score 1):

If the EFS has a Linux-like shell, you can use [`Session.ExecuteCommand`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_executecommand):

```
$session.ExecuteCommand("hdfs dfs -put -f /efs/home/JoeStreet/report-2021-02-02_no_locations.xlsx /prd/product/ssa_stg/JoeStreet/")
```

---

If the server something more non-standard, you might need to use proper SSH (not SFTP) library, like SSH.NET or Posh-SSH.